# Add table data to itself, incrementing timestamp

Tags: database, postgresql, increment

I have a table with dummy data in it, with 40,000 rows, and a timestamp on each row that increments by a few milliseconds. I want to multiply these rows by, say, 10, each 40,000 rows incrementing by a day, and hour, whatever I set it to be.

Is there a way to select data from a table and then feed it back into itself with one column changed slightly?

FWIW, there are 33 columns on this table.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql code from gustavotkg is along the right lines.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (event_ts, col1, col2)
SELECT event_ts + interval '1 day', col1, col2
FROM mytable
WHERE event_ts BETWEEN <something> AND <something else>
```

Repeat with different intervals for multiple copies.

Comment: Yup! Thanks. I had to do some local tweaks to this due to unique ID constraints and date range constraints but this basically works.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you want to just update the rows or also select them at the same time, or even insert new rows. Updating is very simple:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET col1 = col1*10
   ,ts   = ts + interval '1 day'
```

To also return all rows like a `SELECT` statement would (the updated state!):

```
UPDATE tbl
SET col1 = col1*10
  , ts   = ts + interval '1 day'
RETURNING *
```

If you actually want to **`INSERT`** new rows with just one column changed and the timestamp changed, and the point is to **avoid having to type out all 33 columns**, you could:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl_tmp AS SELECT * FROM tbl;
UPDATE tbl_tmp SET col1 = col1*10, ts = ts + interval '1 day';
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT * FROM tbl_tmp;
DROP tbl_tmp;
```

OR somewhat faster with the new [writable CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) in version 9.1:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE ON COMMIT DROP tbl_tmp AS SELECT * FROM tbl;
WITH x AS (
    UPDATE tbl_tmp SET col1 = col1*10, ts = ts + interval '1 day'
    RETURNING *
    )
INSERT INTO tbl SELECT * FROM x;
DROP tbl_tmp;
```

Be sure to have [autovacuum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) running or run [VACUUM ANALYZE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-vacuum.html) manually afterwards.